# MailKit: The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, smtp, mailkit

I got exception when I try to connect to my SMTP server using MailKit SmtpClient. **BUT** my mails have been sent successfully if I use `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient` with the same parameters!

**The exception message**: `An error occurred while attempting to establish an SSL or TLS connection.`

**The inner exception message**: `The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.`

### Questions

- Why does `MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient` throw exception but `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient` doesn't? What is the difference between them?
- How to fix it?

### Code

Initialize the parameters required for mail sending:

```
var host = "myhost.com";
var port = 2525;
var from = "from@mydomain.com";
var to = "to@mydomain.com";
var username = "from@mydomain.com";
var password = "myPassword";
var enableSsl = true;
```

Sending mail using `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient`:

```
var client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
{
    Host = host,
    Port = port,
    EnableSsl = enableSsl,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password)
};

client.Send(from, to, "subject", "body"); // success.
```

But when I try to connect to the host using `MailKit` with the same host and port, I got the exception:

```
var mailKitClient = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient();
mailKitClient.Connect(host, port, enableSsl); // it throws the exception.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are connecting to a plain-text port and expecting SSL.

In MailKit, the true/false `useSsl` parameter is used to decide whether or not to *connect* in SSL mode or plain-text mode.

In System.Net.Mail, they don't support connecting in SSL mode, they only support upgrading a plain-text connection to SSL mode using the STARTTLS command once the connection has been established.

To overcome this, MailKit has a different Connect() method that takes an enum value `SecureSocketOptions`.

What you want is `SecureSocketOptions.StartTls`:

```
var mailKitClient = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient();
mailKitClient.Connect(host, port, SecureSOcketOptions.StartTls);
```